# AngularJS ng-repeat enable sorting on table columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a table from a Array of JSONObject. And want to enable sorting on column header click. My code is as below.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="record in records | orderBy:columnToOrder:reverse" ng-if="$first">
        <td>S.No</td><td ng-repeat="(key,value) in record " ng-click="columnToOrder=key;reverse=!reverse">{{key}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end >
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td ng-repeat="(key,value) in record ">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My data lookg like

```
[
{ Count="85923", Property Name="Name 1"},
{ Count="85933", Property Name="Name 2"},
{ Count="85953", Property Name="Name 3"},
{ Count="85973", Property Name="Name 4"}
]
```

But this code is not working. No error is shown too. Please help me enabling this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the inline, define a method for ordering and use that method during click, since if the variables are defined in inline, the variables are created in the child scope and it would not be available for the parent ng-repeat-start scope.

Controller

```
 $scope.order =function(key) {
    $scope.columnToOrder=key;
    $scope.reverse= !$scope.reverse
};
```

HTML

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="record in records | orderBy:columnToOrder:reverse" ng-if="$first">
            <td>S.No</td><td ng-repeat="(key,value) in record " ng-click="order(key)">{{key}}</td>
        </tr>       
        <tr ng-repeat-end>
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td ng-repeat="(key,value) in record">{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Karthik, It worked for me but as in my question my data has key as words(space in between) and so sorting is not working on that column.